# bash: awk print inside function

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

If I have a function like:

```
function getIP() {
    local ip=$(cat /etc/hosts | awk '/${1:-domain}/{print $1}')
    echo "$ip"
}
```

How do I prevent the $1 from ‘print $1’ from becoming the parameter passed to the function?

So basically I’d like to call it and get something like:  `cat /etc/hosts | awk '/domain/{print $1}'`

but I’m currently, with the default parameter, getting:  `cat /etc/hosts | awk '/domain/{print }'`

and with a passed parameter:  `cat /etc/hosts | awk '/test/{print test}'`

I've tried escaping it but that gives me a bash error:

```
awk: /${1:-domain}/{print \$1}
awk:                      ^ backslash not last character on line
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
getIP() {
    awk -v h="${1:-domain}" '$0 ~ h{print $1}' /etc/hosts
}
```

- to pass a variable to `awk` use `-v varname=value`
- no need to use useless cat
- no need to create a local variable `ip` if you're just doing an `echo`

Comment: Thanks - this does work.  Dumb question (sorry - new to shell), but if you don't echo, how does the function know what to return?

Comment: awk, like echo, prints to stdout, so whatever awk prints, that's what your function prints, and that's what you're capturing with `$()`.

Comment: Just to be clear: While this implements the OPs code correctly, the OPs approach is almost certainly wrong and will produce undesirable output for some values of `$1`. We can't tell without sample input and expected output of course...

Comment: I was able to make it work using the original code by adding eval and escaping the $1: cat /etc/hosts | eval "awk '/${1:-domain}/{print \$1}'"